# Let $G_1,G_2$ be groups, $N$ a normal subgroup of $G_1\times G_2$. Suppose $p_i(N)=G_i$ for all $i\in\{1,2\}$. Does it follow that $N=G_1\times G_2$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups

Let $G_1,G_2$ be groups and $N$ a normal subgroup of $G_1\times G_2$. Let $p_i\colon G_1\times G_2\to G_i$ be the projection with $p_i(g_1,g_2)=g_i$ for $i\in\{1,2\}$.

Suppose $p_i(N)=G_i$ for all $i\in\{1,2\}$. Does it follow that $N=G_1\times G_2$?

My intuition would say that the answer is yes (at least in the case of finite groups), but I am sceptical. Is it also true for infinite groups? And if no, is there a suitable counterexample?

Any facts I am missing are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not exactly a fact you are missing, more a procedure you are missing. Why don't you always test your intuition against small examples - in this case the smallest non-trivial direct product, $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2$?  I mean this in a helpful and not critical way.

Comment: You are right, I just gave in to my first thought and it resulted in tunnel vision. ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

Let $G_1=G_2=G$ be an abelian group and let $N=\{(g,g):g\in G\}$. Then $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G\times G$ and $p_1(N)=p_2(N)=G$ but $N\neq G\times G$.